# .NET Framework compatibility issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr, assemblies, .net-assembly

We have one VB.net Winform application built against .net framework 1.1 uses referenced assemblies (Class Library) from .net 1.1 GAC location and works fine.

But later we have migrated only referenced assembly files to .net 4.0 and deployed those locally in application executable's folder.

So now manifest file of main application which is in .net 1.1 has referenced assemblies in .net Framewok 4.0

And this application works perfectly if we have .NET framework 1.1 installed on client machine and but if i remove .net framewok 1.1 then application crashes while getting data from referenced assemblies.

Client machine has .Net Framewok 4.0 installed and .net runtime supports backward compatibility so why application crashes after removing .NET 1.1 framework.

Please shed some light on this issue. thanks.

Comment: CLR v4 will automatically replace framework assembly requests for .NET 2.0+ assemblies, substituting the 4.0 version of the assembly.  Works because the 4.0 version of them is highly compatible with the 2.0 version and Microsoft thoroughly tested this.  But the buck stops somewhere, it won't do this automatically for 1.x requests.  Too old and not tested.   You'd have to use your own `<bindingRedirect>` to force this.   Hard to guess what "getting data" might mean (why do we have to guess?) but smells like a resource in a .resx file.  Rings a bell, didn't I already tell you this?

Comment: thanks @HansPassant.. I am testing this in Production environment & don't have VS installed in that environment...  Also checked .resx file in another environment (source code) but all resources used in referenced assemblies are of .Net 4.0 assembly versions..